# "Class doesn't support automation." JavaScript error only without Admin permissions

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, permissions, usergroups

I have a WebBrowser control on a WinForms desktop application, browsing an ASP.NET web application containing a short JavaScript function. For the vast majority of users, this happens as it should.

However, on certain machines, users experienced a Script Error, "Class doesn't support automation.", specifying the function in my web app.
Further exploration reveals that, when a user with Admin rights on the machine is logged onto the machine, the application will function as expected. But, when the user logged onto the machine does not have Admin rights, we see the same Script Error.

Is there some entitlement that needs to be assigned to the general users group on this machine (presumably already assigned on the other machines)?